# Path too long exception with FirefoxProfile

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Starting **FirefoxDriver** with **FirefoxProfile** leads to **Exception**: `The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

Catch: this is behavior for Windows User "**Administrator**", with shorter user name like "**xxxxx**" there is no such exception observed.

This behavior most likely depends on profile used & https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/05/04/update-regarding-add-ons-in-firefox/ - there are some **addons** installed (+-15) but before the mozilla fixes all started without exception.

Versions used

- *Selenium 3.141/4.0 alpha*
- *geckodriver 64-bit 0.23/0.24*
- *Firefox 64-bit 66.0.3/66.0.4*

```cs
FirefoxProfile _FirefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(SeleniumFirefoxProfileDirectory); //"C:\\Temp\\FirefoxProfiles\\p2"
FirefoxDriverService driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = _FirefoxProfile;

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService,options,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

**StackTrace**

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String destinationDirectory)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile.WriteToDisk()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile.ToBase64String()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions.GenerateFirefoxOptionsDictionary()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions.ToCapabilities()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.ConvertOptionsToCapabilities(FirefoxOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

Comment: What .net version are you using? Long paths are supported from .net version 4.6.2 and later. For more information see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.1 - <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />

Comment: IMHO Selenium issue - filled bug report - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7181